# How do I order data in a lollipop graph in Shiny based on user inputs?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am creating a simple app in Shiny to learn how it works.

I have a lollipop chart which changes based on user input.

The chart is ordered by country z-a.

I want to be able to order it by the data that is chosen by the user (input ID = dta), from largest at the top to smallest at the bottom.

This I can do in normal R, with for example:

```
data %>%
arrange(Market_size) %>% 
mutate(Country = factor(Country, levels = Country)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(y = Market_size, x = Country)) +
geom_lollipop(aes(color = Region), point.size = 5) +
theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 
13), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 13), 
legend.text=element_text(size=13), legend.title=element_blank()) +
coord_flip() +
xlab("") +
ylab("") +
guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 4)))
```

But I can´t seem to translate this into Shiny.

My code for this part of the Shiny is:

```
# LIBRARIES AND DATA LOAD

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(ggalt)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(plotly)

data <- read_excel("data.xlsx")

# USER INTERFACE

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),

navbarPage(title = "Database",

# HOME TAB

tabPanel("Home",

verticalLayout(

p(strong("Welcome to the database, select above the tabs to navigate."))
)
), 

# SINGLE VARIABLE TAB

tabPanel("Single variable",

sidebarLayout(      

sidebarPanel(

selectInput(inputId = "cntry",
label = "Choose countries:", 
choices= data$Country,
multiple = TRUE),

selectInput(inputId = "rgns",
label = "Choose regions:", 
choices= data$Region,
multiple = TRUE),

selectInput(inputId = "dta",
label = "Choose data:", 
choices= names(data[3:6]),
multiple = FALSE)
),

mainPanel(
plotOutput(outputId = "plot")
)
)
)
)
)

# SERVER

server <- function(input, output) {

# DATA FOR SINGLE VARIABLE TAB AND SINGLE VARIABLE DATA TABLE  

data_subset <- reactive({
filter(data, Country %in% input$cntry | Region %in% input$rgns) %>% 
select(Country, Region, input$dta)
})

# PLOT FOR SINGLE VARIABLE TAB  

output$plot <- renderPlot({
ggplot(data = data_subset(), aes_string(y = input$dta, x = "Country")) +
geom_lollipop(aes(color = Region), point.size = 5) +
theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 
13), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 13), 
legend.text=element_text(size=13), legend.title=element_blank()) +
coord_flip() +
xlab("") +
ylab("") +
guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 4)))
})
}

# RUN THE APP

shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide toy data.

Comment: Yes my data is fictional as this is just for practice, your answer below solved this with an additional part I´ll write below. For others if they stumble across this my data looked like:

Comment: Country, Region, Market_size, No_smokers_18_plus, Daily_users, Closed_system

Comment: Afhanistan, Asia, 784000, 200000, 25000, 0.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
data_subset <- reactive({
filter(data, Country %in% input$cntry | Region %in% input$rgns) %>% 
select(Country, Region, input$dta) %>%
mutate(y_var = .[[input$dta]]
})
```

And then in your ggplot call, change your first line to:

```
ggplot(data = data_subset(), aes(y = y_var, x = Country))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, this worked once I added two more lines to the first bit: mutate(y_var = .[[input$dta]]) %>% arrange(y_var) %>% mutate(Country = factor(Country, levels = Country))